# how do you install drivers

Tags: ati

I am new to ubuntu and put a new graphics card in my computer. I need to know how to install the driver information from the cd, because there is no autoplay or anything like that. I need very simple instructions, because I have never used ubuntu before, I just figured out how to close windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an nVIDIA driver I'd recommend using the built-in `nvidia-current` package.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`

logout & login

then run `nvidia-settings` and adjust your settings to meet your requirements.  Be sure to save the xconfig before you exit `nvidia-settings`

ATI uses the `fglrx` packages
`sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`
`sudo amdcccle` and verify your settings and save.

Logout and login to see your new drivers in action

Answer (score 1):

You can install your graphics card's drivers directly from Ubuntu, you don't need any CD in fact.

### Ubuntu 12.10

Open a Terminal by typing **Terminal** on the Dash. Run this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Then open *Software Sources* from the Dash, go to the *Additional Drivers* tab and select the driver for your graphics card. Then, just apply the changes.

### Older versions

Open Jockey by typing **Additional Drivers** on the Dash. Follow the same steps that above; select your graphic's card drivers and apply the changes.

You can see more about this [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers). See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers).